# Chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127 error while running selenium on flask venv

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, flask, webdriver, jinja2

I am building my first flask app and am having trouble integrating selenium. The app takes an input from an html text field, uses it to pass into a search field with selenium, then runs some code. However, I am getting the following error after entering something into the text field and hitting submit:

```
An error occurred in get_lyrics: Message: Service /home/vsherr/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

An error occurred: Message: Service /home/vsherr/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

[2023-12-29 12:30:52,471] ERROR in app: Exception on /search [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/vsher/Desktop/misc-coding/lyyric/search.py", line 19, in search
    word_list = get_lyrics(song)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/vsher/Desktop/misc-coding/lyyric/search.py", line 34, in get_lyrics
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/vsherr/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/vsher/Desktop/misc-coding/lyyric/search.py", line 25, in search
    return render_template('error.html', error_message=str(e))
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 151, in render_template
    template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 126, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 65, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/home/vsherr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 99, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: error.html
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2023 12:30:52] "POST /search HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have tried upgrading selenium and installing a number of packages, including:
`pip install -U selenium`
`pip install --upgrade chromedriver-autoinstaller`
`sudo apt-get install -y chromium-browser`

What might be causing this?

Edit: I have narrowed it down but still haven't solved the issue. It has to do with chromedriver not working in Ubuntu. Previous solutions have involved editing the filepath to get to the chromedriver. However, this solution has become obsolete as chromedriver no longer requires a filepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! Had to do with broken dependencies / installations. Using pip install dependencies solved the first issue. Then I used `sudo apt --fix-broken install` to fix all this installs. Works perfectly now.